# How do I keep track of a reported Jobs listing?

Tags: support, flags, stack-overflow-jobs

I reported a Job just now for inconsistency in company details, but now I realise that I have no way of tracking what happens next. The *Report* button features a flag, but there's no mention of this in my flags.

[image]

How do I know if somebody followed up, other than monitoring the job itself?

Comment: Not sure because I never flagged a job offer, but is there something helpful here https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages ? Maybe "Blocked employers" ?

Comment: @Arount thanks, but nothing there. Since a flag isn't sent to the company (at least, I hope it isn't), presumably it isn't a message/question, and I hope simply reporting a listing doesn't automatically block the company.